# Labeling only maximum value when zoomed out or print in smaller scale

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression, rule-based, geometry-generator

I would like to prioritise the maximum values to be shown on the map. In other words, when the label collides it should drop out the minimum values.

In the shown examples, I would like to have priority for -5.86 over -5.91 when I print/zoom in a smaller scale.

[image: larger scale]

[image: smaller scale]

Answer (score 1):

Is not easy to manipulate the *Automated Placement Engine* behavior, but you can try assigning a *Data Defined Priority* placement, based on the content of one field:

[image: 1]

---

Select *Edit* in the *Data Defined Priority* menu and write an expression.

You can calculate in that expression a value between 0 and 10. Or you can refer that expression directly to a field, manually or with an expression populated:

```
(("presion" - minimum("presion"))
 /
 (maximum("presion") - minimum("presion")))
* 10
```

In my case *'presion'* is the name of a field that I want to use as priority.

With that expression, I am assigning a value of 0 to the minimum, a value of 10 to the maximum, and a linear interpolation to the others.